# crashing after cout prints object getter

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, std, destructor

basically my code is crashing and I cant find out why, I have used the Code::Blocks debugger but no help for me. it crashes AFTER it prints out the correct data for properties[4]. I know this is not the optimal way to do this but it is for a class where I need to show multiple ways it can be done. My issue is after it displays "River Kwai Restaurant" it crashes and cant figure out why.

```
const int MAX_PROPERTIES = 5;

int main(void) {
   Property properties[MAX_PROPERTIES];
   Rentals tempRent;

  tempRent = Rentals();
   tempRent.setBond(10000);
   tempRent.setMonthlyRent(700);

   tempRent.setOwner("River Kwai Restaurant");
   tempRent.setAddress("3 Bishopton Road");
   tempRent.setSuburb("Footscray");
   tempRent.setPostcode(5000);

   properties[4] = tempRent;
   tempRent.~Rentals();

   cout << properties[4].getOwner() << endl;


   return 0;
}

Property::Property(){
   owner = "NULL";
   address = "NULL";
   suburb = "NULL";
   postcode = 0;
}

Property::Property(string theOwner, string theAddress,
                   string theSuburb, int thepostCode):
                     owner(theOwner), address(theAddress),
                     suburb(theSuburb), postcode(thepostCode){}

Property::~Property() {}

Rentals::Rentals(string theOwner, string theAddress, string theSuburb,
                  int thePostCode, double theBond, double theMonthlyRent):
                  Property(theOwner, theAddress, theSuburb, thePostCode),
                  bond(theBond), monthlyRent(theMonthlyRent){}

Rentals::Rentals() : Property() {
   owner = "NULL";
   address = "NULL";
   suburb = "NULL";
   postcode = 0;
   bond = 0;
   monthlyRent = 0;
}

Rentals::~Rentals() {}
```

NOTE: removing the destructor does fix it, but I would like to know why? should the destructor not effect properties[4] at all since it is already initialized?

That is the relevant code but I will post the entire code / header files below if needed.

```
#include "property_a.h"
#include "rentals.h"
#include "commercial.h"
#include "sales.h"

const int MAX_PROPERTIES = 5;

int main(void) {
   Property properties[MAX_PROPERTIES];
   Rentals tempRent;

   properties[0] = Commercial("Notting Hill McDonalds",
                              "4 Gardiner Road", "Notting Hill", 5000,
                              "Li3000");

   properties[1] = Rentals("Janet Dalgleish", "30 Firhill Court",
                           "Mary Hill", 4000, 500.00, 300.00);

   properties[2] = Sales("Robert Burns", "3 Ayr Court", "Irvine", 4000,
                         "10/10/2015", 700000);

   properties[3] = Property();
   properties[3] = properties[0];


   tempRent = Rentals();
   tempRent.setBond(10000);
   tempRent.setMonthlyRent(700);

   tempRent.setOwner("River Kwai Restaurant");
   tempRent.setAddress("3 Bishopton Road");
   tempRent.setSuburb("Footscray");
   tempRent.setPostcode(5000);

   properties[4] = tempRent;

   cout << properties[4].getOwner() << endl;


   return 0;
}

Property::Property(){
   owner = "NULL";
   address = "NULL";
   suburb = "NULL";
   postcode = 0;
}

Property::Property(string theOwner, string theAddress,
                   string theSuburb, int thepostCode):
                     owner(theOwner), address(theAddress),
                     suburb(theSuburb), postcode(thepostCode){}

Property::~Property() {}

Commercial::Commercial() : Property() {
   owner = "NULL";
   address = "NULL";
   suburb = "NULL";
   postcode = 0;
   license = "NULL";
}

Commercial::Commercial(string theOwner, string theAddress,
                        string theSuburb, int thepostCode,
                        string theLicense): Property(theOwner, theAddress,
                        theSuburb, thepostCode), license(theLicense) {}

Commercial::~Commercial() {}

Rentals::Rentals(string theOwner, string theAddress, string theSuburb,
                  int thePostCode, double theBond, double theMonthlyRent):
                  Property(theOwner, theAddress, theSuburb, thePostCode),
                  bond(theBond), monthlyRent(theMonthlyRent){}

Rentals::Rentals() : Property() {
   owner = "NULL";
   address = "NULL";
   suburb = "NULL";
   postcode = 0;
   bond = 0;
   monthlyRent = 0;
}

Rentals::~Rentals() {}

Sales::Sales(string theOwner, string theAddress, string theSuburb,
               int thepostCode, string theAuctionDate, double thePrice):
               Property(theOwner, theAddress, theSuburb, thepostCode),
               auctionDate(theAuctionDate), price(thePrice) {}

Sales::Sales() : Property() {
   owner = "NULL";
   address = "NULL";
   suburb = "NULL";
   postcode = 0;
   auctionDate = "NULL";
   price = 0;
}

Sales::~Sales() {}
```

Property header

```
#ifndef __PROPERTY_A_H__
#define __PROPERTY_A_H__


/*TODO  REQUIRED HEADER FILES AND NAMESPACES*/
#include <string>
#include "utility1.h"


class Property
{
protected:
  string owner;
  string address;
  string suburb;
  int postcode;

public:
  Property();
  Property(string theOwner, string theAddress, string theSuburb, int thepostCode);
  virtual ~Property();

  string getOwner() const {return owner;};   //Note the use of const
  string getAddress() const {return address;};
  string getSuburb() const {return suburb;};
  int getPostcode() const {return postcode;};

  void setOwner(string newOwner) {owner = newOwner;};
  void setAddress(string newAddress) {address = newAddress;};
  void setSuburb( string  newSuburb) {suburb = newSuburb;};
  void setPostcode(int  newPostcode) {postcode = newPostcode;};
};
#endif
```

Rentals header

```
#ifndef __RENTALS_H__
#define __RENTALS_H__


#include "property_a.h"

class Rentals : public Property
{
protected:
  double bond;
  double monthlyRent;

public:
  Rentals();
  Rentals(string theOwner, string theAddress, string theSuburb,
              int thepostCode, double theBond, double theMonthlyRent);
   ~Rentals() ;

  double getBond() const {return bond;};   //Note the use of const

  void setBond(double theBond) {bond = theBond;};

  double getMonthlyRent() const {return monthlyRent;};   //Note the use of const

  void setMonthlyRent(double theMonthlyRent) {monthlyRent = theMonthlyRent;};


};

#endif
```

Comment: you should google `object slice`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another commenter suggested you lookup [object slicing.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing)  That does describe the issue, but you can see it more concretely by adding some debugging statements to your code:

```
std::cout << "Size of properties: " << sizeof(properties) << std::endl;
std::cout << "Size of properties[4]: " << sizeof(properties[4]) <<std::endl;
std::cout << "Size of tmpRent: "<< sizeof(tempRent) <<std::endl;
```

The output looks like this:

```
Size of properties: 440
Size of properties[4]: 88
Size of tmpRent: 104
```

It looks like one properties element isn't big enough to hold an element of your subclasses... what's going on?

When you declare `Properties properties[5]`, you are declaring an array of objects of type Properties and it allocates a contiguous block of memory.  You can actually see that by printing out the addresses:

```
std::cout << "Start of properties: " << &properties <<std::endl;
std::cout << "Address of properties[0]: " << &properties[0] << std::endl;
std::cout << "Address of properties[1]: " << &properties[1] << std::endl;
std::cout << "Address of properties[2]: " << &properties[2] << std::endl;
std::cout << "Address of properties[3]: " << &properties[3] << std::endl;
std::cout << "Address of properties[4]: " << &properties[4] << std::endl;
```

On my machine I get:

```
Start of properties: 0x7fff5a4c6070
Address of properties[0]: 0x7fff5a4c6070
Address of properties[1]: 0x7fff5a4c60c8
Address of properties[2]: 0x7fff5a4c6120
Address of properties[3]: 0x7fff5a4c6178
Address of properties[4]: 0x7fff5a4c61d0
```

Those are large numbers, but you can see that the address is increasing by 0x58 or 88 bytes for each element in your array.  When you assign into properties[4], C++ is treating properties[4] as a pointer, and copying 104 bytes into where it points.  The assignment properties[4] = tempRent is equivalent to `memcpy(&tempRent, &properties[4], 104)`.  C++ just assumes you have enough memory there to hold the object (which is 104 bytes). But there are only 88 bytes left until the end of the block of memory.  Your assignment is overwriting the end of the array and corrupting the next segment of memory.  The program may crash at any time, it may display corrupt data, or it may seem to work perfectly fine (as it does when I run it on my Mac.)

Comment: That makes perfect sense thanks, but I don't really understand that it crashes when calling only property[4] functions since it should corrupt the next memory not the current one. is it just unlucky it is corrupting and crashing where it does? or is it missing something that says end of class at the end of the of the 88 bytes of information?

Comment: also does this mean that doing the proper method of creating an array of pointers will fix this issue as using the new keyword when declaring properties[4] = new Rentals() will allocate Rentals() size memory (this case 104 bytes) to properties[4] not 88 bytes?

Comment: @RoryThoman you are right about the 'lucky' part. You really have no idea where it is going to crash.  If the memory block is right on the edge of valid allocated memory, then your process might crash when you write into properties[4], but its most likely that your program already "owns" the adjacent space, so the operating system won't help you out with a segmentation fault.  

Creating an array of pointers will allow you to assign any type of Properties, but you'll have to allocate memory for it first.  Rentals *tempRental = new Rentals().  Also, you'll have to remember to delete the memory.